# While loop not working as intended

Tags: java

Why aren't the entered numbers adding up for the sum at the end of the program?

```
      int data;
      int sum = 0;


      int count =0;
      do {
         System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
         data = input.nextInt();
         count++;
      }       


      while (count < 10);



      while (sum !=0) 

         break;

      System.out.println("The total is " + sum);

   }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a pointless while loop and why not use a for loop? Also, you never even increment `sum`, so what do you expect?

Comment: How could it? You're never changing the value of `sum` after the initial assignment of 0. --- Also, your do-while loop looks weird and detached. Put the `while` on the same line as `}`. --- And what do you think the `while (sum !=0) break;` loop is doing, and why do you think so? --- And finally, after getting a value and assigning it to `data`, don't you maybe want to use the value for something?

Comment: For some reason a line didn't copy, I have "sum += data;" above my second while statement. I had to include the "break;" line because without it my program would constantly add the last number entered to itself.

Comment: Please edit your question so that we can see the correct code.  We can't help you figure out the problems in your code if we're looking at the wrong code.

Answer (score 1):

Lets tidy things up
and after count++; I add a line that will sum your value e.g. sum += data;

```
int data;
int sum = 0;
int count =0;
do {
  System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
  data = input.nextInt();
  count++;
  sum += data;      // new line here to sum value
}  while (count < 10);

System.out.println("The total is " + sum);
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so very much. I had extra lines in there for no reason. I did have a sum += data; line in there, I don't know why it didn't copy for this, but I had it above my second while statement. I'm a noob.

Comment: Glad to be of help.  if this answer helped you please consider to upvote and/or accept - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Breaking down the code we can see where the issue would be.

You initialize your variables.

```
  int data;
  int sum = 0;


  int count =0;
```

This part appears correct.

Then you start your first loop to obtain your data from the user.

```
  do {
     System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
     data = input.nextInt();
     count++;
  }       


  while (count < 10);
```

Here we see that for each time we iterate the loop we set the variable 'data' to the inputed value and increment the counter. The loop is executed 10 times.

At the point we exit the loop are variables would be set as follows:

```
    data = `last number entered by the user`
    sum = 0
    count = 10
```

Now we look at the last loop.

```
  while (sum !=0) 

     break;
```

Since 'sum' = 0 we never enter the loop.

Finally, we have the print statement.

```
  System.out.println("The total is " + sum);
```

Since 'sum' = 0 the line printed will say `The total is 0`

if you modify your first loop to...

```
do {
   System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
   data = input.nextInt();
   sum = sum + data;
   count++;
}       


while (count < 10);
```

then you should get the sum of the inputed data.

Additionally, your second loop should be removed as even when 'sum' is not equal to 0 it will enter the loop and immediately hit the break statement causing it to exit the loop.